# Best way to restrict page access?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, routes, react-router-v4

I'm designing a website with a form component that redirects to a "failure" or "success" component based on whether the form submits without an error or not. Here is the code I'm using:

```js
await axios
  .post('/api/patients/', data, axiosConfig)
  .then((response) => {
    history.push('/success');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    history.push('/failure');
  });
```

This works well even when I intentionally make a bad request by turning my network off or changing the route. However, I can type in the "/success" route in my browser and access it whether or not I've submitted the form. How do I restrict this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible to track that the route was entered manually, but you can pass to the "success" component props like "submit: true", and render component if this props exist.

```
await axios
.post('/api/patients/', data, axiosConfig)
    .then((response) => {
        history.push({
          pathname: '/success',
          state: { submit: true }
        });
 })
 .catch((error) => {
   history.push({
     pathname: '/failure',
     state: { submit: true }
   });
 });
```

And in "success" component check props like:

```
if (props.location.state.submit) { . . . }
```

Comment: Hey, I'm having trouble accessing the state in the Success component. Should I use something like Redux or Context for a global state thing? Because initially I was thinking of that but I'd have to find a way to reset the state each time the user leaves the success/fail page

Comment: @JM223 I think you can use redux or local storage to set submit: true and in success component on unmount set submit: false